# Issue while embedding css in the php code?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to display 2 images with their created time to be displayed parallely in wordpress . So tried to write css (display flex) using 'echo' command . Although logic is correct but  tag  of the image is not working and  there may be other syntactical error.As the beginners please review the code and help me.

In this below, if i close table tag before div it is not working properly.

```
<?php
  $dir = opendir('/var/www/html/data1/products/images/avhrr/rgb');
  $files = array();
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) 
    {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' ) continue;
    if (is_dir("/var/www/html/data1/products/images/avhrr/rgb/$file")) continue;
    $lastModified = filemtime("/var/www/html/data1/products/images/avhrr/rgb/$file");
    $files[$file] = $lastModified;
    }
  closedir($dir);
  asort($files);
  $files=array_reverse($files);
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($files as $file => $lastModified) 
  $name = basename($file);
   $str = $name;
   $pattern = "/top/i";
  
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches))
{
$file_stats = stat("/var/www/html/data1/products/images/avhrr/rgb/".$name);
echo '<div class="container" style="display:flex">';
echo '<table border="5">';
echo '<tr><td>';
echo 'Daily_RGB : '.date('d-m-Y h:m:i A',$file_stats["mtime"]).PHP_EOL; //Equivalent of filemtime()
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='/data1/products/images/avhrr/rgb/$file'  target='_blank'></a>";
echo "<img src='/data1/products/images/avhrr/rgb/$file' height='450' width='450'/>";
echo '</td></tr>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</table>';
$count++;
}
 if ($count == 2) break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: For starters, you have `<div><table>` at the beginning of what you are creating there, but `</div></table>` at the end - doesn't match, nesting error.

Comment: Plus, if you wanted to use the `flex` on that div element to get the images next to each other - then that div would have to contain _both_ the tables you are creating there. But you are creating a new div for each table.